# How do I set a binding property via a style in XAML?

Tags: validation, binding

I have a data template for a type that defines a bunch of data entry fields, all with similar settings on the textboxes, something like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ContactInfo">
  <DockPanel>
    <HeaderedContentControl Header="Contact Name">
      <TextBox Width="200" Text="{Binding Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
    </HeaderedContentControl>
    <HeaderedContentControl Header="Contact Quest">
      <TextBox Width="200" Text="{Binding Quest, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
    </HeaderedContentControl>
    <HeaderedContentControl Header="Contact Favorite Color">
      <TextBox Width="200" Text="{Binding Color, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
    </HeaderedContentControl>
  </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I would like to reduce duplication as much as possible and eliminate as many of the duplicated properties as I can.  I know that I can get rid of the repeated Width attribute by adding

```
<DataTemplate.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="x:Type TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
  </Style>
</DataTemplate.Resources>
```

to the DataTemplate.  However, I also want to get rid of the redundant "ValidatesOnDataErrors=True" setting.

I have tried modifying the style to set it thusly:

```
<DataTemplate.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="x:Type TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
    <Setter Property="Text.Binding.ValidatesOnDataErrors" Value="True"/>
  </Style>
</DataTemplate.Resources>
```

but at compile time it complains about ValidatesOnDataErrors not being resolvable.

How does one accomplish what I want?  I have upwards of 50 fields to style, and I don't want to change all of them one by one if I decide to change my validation technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_SelfValidatingTextBox.aspx) will be helpfull.

Comment: It's helpful in that it is exactly the problem I'm seeing, it's unhelpful in that I hoped there would be an easier solution.  If nothing better comes along, I'll probably use this approach.

Unfortunately, up-voting this answer requires more reputation than I have, otherwise I would.

Comment: I know have the reputation :-)